# Using count I'm only getting one row back

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table like the following

```
User   Item
 A      1
 A      1
 A      1
 B      1
 B      2
 C      2
 C      2
 A      2
```

I'm trying to run a query so I can get an output such as

```
User    Item    Count
 A       1       3
 B       1       1
 B       2       1
 A       2       1
 C       2       2
```

I've tried the following query, however I'm not getting the output right.

```
  select f.item,f.uid, COUNT(f.uid) as count 
    from fresh f, 
         product p
   where f.locationid = p.iid   
group by f.locationid, f.uid 
order by f.uid desc;
```

Can anyone point out how I write a query to get the required output? I could write it up in python / ruby but I think it'll take a lot longer to run! :(

Comment: Why are you grouping by f.locationid and f.uid?  If you group by only f.uid, you might get the results you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select user, Item, count(*) Count From tablename
Group by User, Item
Order by Item
```

Comment: +1 for the only answer that shows order by item, which seems to be the only problem with @steve's original query.

Comment: ...although for clarity most programmers would order by item,uid, as something there is in a programmer that hates randomness.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT user, item, count(*) FROM fresh GROUP BY user, item
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you joining to the product table, when it is not used in the results?

That is likely cause of the issue, since it is an inner join, when there isn't a match, there will be no result, so you'll lose data, try just:

```
select 
    item,
    uid, 
    COUNT(*) as count 
from  
    fresh
group by 
    locationid,
    uid 
order by
    uid desc
;
```

Comment: I'm joining to make sure its a valid product for a specific shop. If the iid isn't in there I don't want it in the result set. Does that make sense?

Comment: Um, the validity should have been checked on the way in via foreign key.